OIDC Handler cannot seem to read or redirect to my keycloak authorization endpoint
I'm trying to implement OIDC auth against a Keycloak identity provider in a .NetCore 8.0 MVC application. However, when I hit the challenge, I consistently get the error:

Cannot redirect to the authorization endpoint, the configuration may be missing or invalid.

Here is the configuration in program.cs
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
    .AddCookie()
    .AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
    {
        options.SignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.Authority = "https://mykeycloak.com/auth/realms/myrealm";
        options.ClientId = "my-app-clientid"; //public client so no secret needed
        //options.ClientSecret = "";
        options.CallbackPath = "/auth";
        options.RequireHttpsMetadata = true;
        options.MetadataAddress = "https://mykeycloak.com/auth/realms/myrealm/.well-known/openid-configuration";
        options.SaveTokens = true;
        options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
        options.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.Code;
    });

If I take the value from metadataaddress and throw it in the browser, I definitely get the odic configuration for keycloak -- so it does seem to be valid.  There is definitely a value for authorization_endpoint in the configuration and if I grab that value and throw it in the url of my browser (along with additional required parms) it definitely displays the Keycloak login.
It would appear that the OpenIdConnecHandler is somehow unable to either read or parse the configuration -- but I have no idea why.
Is there something wrong with my configuration?  Is there something special that has to be done when dealing with Keycloak? 

Based on your scenario and descriptions, couple of thing you should take care of. First of all, ensure the MetadataAddress and Authority URLs are correct and accessible, and that the Keycloak client configuration matches your application settings. Enable detailed logging to pinpoint issues and verify that network connectivity, SSL certificates, and CORS settings are correctly configured. Double-check that the CallbackPath in your application matches exactly with what's registered in Keycloak.

I finally solved this by adding the following in the above configuration of AddOpenidConnect:
options.Events.OnRedirectToIdentityProvider = async context =>
{
    context.ProtocolMessage.IssuerAddress = "https://mykeycloak.com/auth/realms/myrealm/protocol/openid-connect/auth";
    await Task.FromResult(0);
};

It appears that the MS OpenidConnectHandler.HandleChallengeAsyncInternal doesn't actually read the Auth Endpoint from the well-known configuration (maybe a bug?).  Looking at the MS code, it seems as though it should be reading the value and populating the IssuerAddress -- but since it wasn't reading that value, IssuerAddress was always empty.  I had to update it manually.
